# Vertical centering imageview in relativelayout

Tags: android, imageview, vertical-alignment

I know this is a popular question but all the answers I found either don't work or break my layout. I'm writing the layout for a listview item, it should simply be a textview on the left and an image on the right, no problem with that. I tried using android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" but that changes nothing. I also tried changing my LinearLayout into a RelativeLayout and using layout_centerVertical="true", that centers horizontally but images on rows with different heights are slightly larger than others. This is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Titolo di prova lorem ipsus dolor sit amet..."
                android:id="@+id/article_title"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Autore di prova"
                android:id="@+id/article_info"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="non dovresti poter vedere questa scritta..."
                android:id="@+id/article_hiddenid"/>
        </LinearLayout>
<!-- Here's where it should be centered -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/demoimage2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/article_image"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

edit: Here's how it looks imgur.com/a/3ZGrl. If i use a RelativeLayout and layout_centerVertical it looks like this: imgur.com/a/vWrzH(some images are slightly wider than others)

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting too many LinearLayout without cause.

Firstly, try setting the orientation for the parent LinearLayout to horizontal. And remove the second nested layout. Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Titolo di prova lorem ipsus dolor sit amet..."
            android:id="@+id/article_title"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Autore di prova"
            android:id="@+id/article_info"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/demoimage2"
                android:id="@+id/article_image"/>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup but nothing changed, it's the same as before

Comment: Could you please share an image of what is the output and what are you expecting

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/3ZGrl this is how it looks on my phone. You can see the images on the right are not vertically centered on the news which have more a title longer than 3 lines. If i use RelativeLayout and layout_centerVertical the images are centered but they are slightly larger on the news with more than 3 lines of title. It's not by much but it's weird http://imgur.com/a/vWrzH

Comment: Please check i have edited the answer this should work now

Comment: it now centers the image but it also breaks the whole layout. See: http://imgur.com/a/VMoXF

Comment: That is indeed strange. I have edited the answer and removed minHieght form the parent LinearLayout and layout_gravity from the ImageView. Try it once and share the screenshot

Comment: @MarcoCutecchia Any luck with the new changes ?

Comment: no, it's still the same as before. Layout is still broken